# Why is $\operatorname{Tr}([A,B]^{m}) = \operatorname{Tr}([AB, [A,B]^{m-1}])$, if [A,[A,B]]=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why is $\operatorname{Tr}([A,B]^{m}) = \operatorname{Tr}([AB, [A,B]^{m-1}])$, where $[A,B] = AB-BA$ for two quadratic matrices $A,B$ with$ [A,[A,B]]=0$ and $Tr$ is the trace of a matrix?

I tried to rewrite this and reduce it to $\operatorname{Tr}([A,B]^{m-1} AB) = \operatorname{Tr}(BA [A,B]^{m-1} ) $ the following way:

$$[A,B]^m = (AB-BA) [A,B]^{m-1} $$
$$[AB,[A,B]^{m-1}] = AB [A,B]^{m-1} - [A,B]^{m-1} AB$$

But now I do not see how to use $[A,[A,B]] = 0$.

Does anyone has hints for this or a hint how to advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From
$$[A,[A,B]]=0$$
we have that
$$A[A,B]=[A,B]A$$
And
$$A[A,B]^n=[A,B]^nA$$
So using your work:
$$\text{Tr}([A,B]^{m-1}AB)=\text{Tr}(B[A,B]^{m-1}A)=\text{Tr}(BA[A,B]^{m-1})$$
which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Thanks, I looked for such an identity and somehow did not see it. :)

Comment: @MPB94 which one was new? The one from the commutator? I didn't see that for the first time either, just when I wrote everything down :)

Comment: $A[A,B] = [A,B] A$. I somehow wanted something like that and did not see it haha.